# How to skip scanning a line when piping in input?

Tags: c, list, scanf, stdin

I am trying to pipe in input through stdin in the C programming language. I have a text file that I would like to read, however, the first line is just the header, so I need to somehow skip it and read the rest.

Example:

Name Grade Points Average

Lea A     4.0    3.3

...

I would like to place each line in a node as part of a linked list and so far all I have are the structures. I am unsure of how I am supposed to read the file.

For reference, what type in the command line will be the following:

./codename < input.txt

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. (I suppose it is that you don't know how to read the input in the first place; that is easily googleable.) If you show us some code we may be able to help better, or you may figure it out yourself.

Comment: Note that the command line shown does not involve a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Use tail with -n:

```
tail -n+2 input.txt | codename
```

Alternatively, if you *must* read the file directly via the < operator, the easiest way is to call getline and throw out the output. You could also do something similar with fgets. You will have to modify the program directly to do that however.